# $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $(S,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Let $A \in \Sigma$. We can define $A \cap \Sigma:=\{A \cap M:M \in \Sigma\}$ and $A \cap \Sigma$ is $\sigma$-algebra on $A$.

**Question**

Can we claim $A \cap \Sigma \subset \Sigma$ ? Is this meaningless?

Comment: Since $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $A\cap M\in\Sigma$ for all $M\in\Sigma$, no?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you. But strictly speaking, should we write $i(A \cap \Sigma) \subset \Sigma$ ? where $i:A \to S$ is injection.

Comment: That $A\cap \Sigma\subset \Sigma$ means simply that for every $B\in A\cap \Sigma$, we also have that $B\in \Sigma$. So this makes sense to write.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. For example, $U \in \Sigma$ with $U \subset A$, $U \in A \cap \Sigma$ holds ?

Comment: If $U\subset A$, then $U=A\cap U$ which is in $A\cap\Sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that statement makes sense. I would like to invent a different notation which I hope will be clearer:

If $\langle S, \Sigma\rangle$ is a measurable space, and $A \in \Sigma$ is a measurable set, define

$$\Sigma_A \equiv \{A\cap M : M\in \Sigma\}.$$

What sort of object is $\Sigma_A$?  It is a collection of subsets of $S$, just like $\Sigma$ is a collection of subsets of $S$.

Because the intersection of any two measurable sets is measurable, it follows that each member of $\Sigma_A$ is in fact a measurable set (each member is the intersection of the measurable set $A$ and some other measurable set $M$.)

Because $\Sigma$ contains *all* the measureable sets, we know that $$\Sigma_A \subseteq \Sigma.$$

---

I think one way to clear up the confusion is to keep careful track of which sets contain *points* (like $S$ and $A$) and which objects contain *subsets of $S$* (like $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma_A$).

As whether you need to include the inclusion $i:A \hookrightarrow S$: we can either deal with these objects $S$, $\Sigma$, $A$, $\Sigma_A$ as *sets*, or we can remember that they are in fact the ingredients for particular measurable spaces.

If we are dealing with them as *sets*, then we can just write
$$\Sigma_A \subseteq \Sigma$$
which is a true statement because each element of $\Sigma_A$ is indeed an element of $\Sigma$.

But we could also notice that $\Sigma_A$ allows you to define a new measurable space — a *measurable subspace* of $\langle S, \Sigma\rangle$. This subspace is  $$\langle A, \Sigma_A\rangle$$
which you can prove satisfies all the axioms of a measurable space. And there is a *measurable function* (a morphism of measurable spaces) between them, given by the inclusion 
$$ i : \langle A, \Sigma_A\rangle \hookrightarrow \langle S, \Sigma\rangle$$

which sends points in $A$ to their equivalents in $S$.

Moral: we only need inclusions when we are dealing with these objects as spaces rather than collections of points.